# Are there known limitations and workarounds for botframework messages delivered on Telegram?

Tags: telegram-bot, botframework

I have noticed a few things by working with the same bot in different channels. Through the web chat, for instance, if I follow the markdown recommended in the documentation, I'm able to send picture links. The same is not true for Telegram, where such messages never end up being delivered.
I've noticed the same behavior for the following scenarios:

- sending pictures as attachments
- sending long text messages

Is there any workaround for this? So far, my approach has been to simplify what's delivered on Telegram, such as showing hyperlinks for pictures, and summarizing long text messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A current limitation of Telegram markdown is that it doesn't support image links. Please see [Telegram Bot API / formatting options](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options) for reference.

In addition, the Bot Framework has an issue with markdown formatting for Telegram. In particular, unordered lists and horizontal rules can cause the message to be rejected. The development team is working on a fix now.